# undefined function imagecreatefrompng() with PHP7.0

Tags: php, laravel, gd

I used to install GD:

sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd

and also

sudo apt-get install php-gd

but still not working!!

Im using Ubuntu 16.04.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working now!!

what I did:

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.0-gd

sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

with `sudo phpenmod gd` , i got:

WARNING: Module gd ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/5.6/mods-available
WARNING: Module gd ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/5.6/mods-available

then:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd
sudo phpenmod gd
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Is there a solution that does not involve downgrading PHP?